# Injecting maven properties to resources

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I'm trying to achieve a relatively simple task - To inject a maven property to my properties file.
In my `pom.xml` I have:

```
<properties>
    <rt.env>staging</rt.env>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>13</java.version>
    <artifact-name>MY-App</artifact-name>
    <heroku.appName>my-app-${rt.env}</heroku.appName>
</properties>
```

In the build section:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${artifact-name}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

and in my resources folder I have a properties file with property:

```
runtime.environment=${rt.env}
```

But after creating the `jar` file using `mvn install` the properties file inside the `jar` does not get the value of the property from the pom file.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you a spring boot application it's better to go with Spring Boot profiles instead of filtering things ...

Comment: @khmarbaise could be, but it's much more work